# ScrollView not working in iPad simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

First off, how do you test scrolling in the iPad simulator? I have a touch pad and I've tried dragging two fingers and I've tried click & dragging two fingers, but I can't get it to scroll.  Am I doing that part correctly?

Assuming that I'm testing properly, why won't my scrollview scroll?  I have a basic view controller in my storyboard and I dragged a scrollview into it.  I made an outlet from it into my code and then in my code I generate a bunch of buttons and add them to this scrollview.  They get displayed properly.  Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios scrollview cunundrum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347671/ios-scrollview-cunundrum)

Comment: Have you tried it on a device, or with a mouse and just clicked and dragged?

Comment: I've just tried it in the simulator.  Also, it's tough to click and drag because my scrollview contains a bunch of buttons, thus whenever I click, my action gets performed

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was I never setContentsize.

Comment: That's always the problem with scrollviews ! =) I wonder why Apple didn't set a default content size which is the size to fit each subviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set scrollview content size such

```
[MyScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
```

this is for iPhone for example.

You can also make two fingers by press the alt key next to cmd in mac 
HOLD PRESS alt + mouse move on simulator

Answer (score 1):

set contentsize of the scrollview,to enable scroll.

Detailed explanation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the contentSize of scrollView which is generally bigger in frame than parentview or its frame to make it scrollable.

```
[viw setContentSize:CGRectMake(width,height)];
```

set it in viewDidLoad or where You alloc srollview.